# How to make this code to loop 10 times per page?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("dbsql", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testimonial where approved='Yes'");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Review</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['full_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['review'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
SELECT * FROM testimonial where approved='Yes'
```

with

```
$offset = 0; //calculate your offset here as per page;

SELECT * FROM testimonial where approved='Yes' limit $offset, 10
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for that specific block of data to loop 10 times every time the page is loaded simply use a for() loop

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
  // block of data
}
```

But I assume that that is not what you are asking since it would be impractical (as far as I can see).

To print 10 results, add

```
limit 10
```

to the end of your query. If you're using pagination, however, you will need to start the limit somewhere (e.g. limit STARTING_NUMBER, NUM_OF_RESULTS)

Good luck!
Dennis M.